# How to remove username from Django registration 1.0

Tags: django, django-registration, authentication

I have customize Django 1.5 (from djangoproject docs) authentication to login with email instead of username and its working perfect, but I am using Django-registration 1.0 to register users.

How do I remove the username field from django registration so users will only need to enter e-mail & password when registering.

Thank you all in advance.
Yaniv M

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started.
Create your own form that is a subclass of RegistrationForm.

In forms.py

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):

    # Override RegistrationForm
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.pop('username')
```

In views.py

```
from registration.views import RegistrationView

from yourapp.forms import MyRegistrationForm


class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    form_class = MyRegistrationForm
```

In urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(),
    name='registration'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom form class based on default `RegistrationForm` and use that class in the `RegistrationView` view.

Comment: With a custom form class will I'll be able to remove the requirement of username field? or just add custom fields to the registration form?

Comment: In the custom class you can remove username field entirely or make it optional.

Answer (score 0):

As-is, it's complicated. You need to:

- [apply this patch](https://bitbucket.org/LinnTroll/django-registration-1.5/commits/c71d5b8e273551cffdfc7869545430e3) because in d-r-1.0, models.py assumes your User model has a "username" field
- create your own "backend" by copy/pasting/editing registration/backends/default/views.py
- copy/paste/edit the registration form as well from registration/forms.py
- most of the time you can use the registration views without modification